# Does grunt-contrib-watch have different output styles?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am using grunt-contrib-watch to compile my LESS files and was wondering if there is an option for line comments like in Compass that says where the selectors were defined? I believe its line_comments in Compass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set [`dumplinenumbers`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less#dumplinenumbers) to 'comments' in your `less` task setup.